# Data Subset error in R using %in% wildcard

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, time-series

My df:

```
> str(merged)
'data.frame':   714 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Date         : Date, format: "2013-03-29" "2013-03-29" "2013-03-29" "2013-03-29" ...
 $ patch        : Factor w/ 7 levels "BVG1","BVG11",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 ...
 $ prod         : num  2.93 2.77 2.86 2.87 3.01 ...
 $ workmix_pct  : int  100 10 16 13 17 21 22 100 11 19 ...
 $ jobcounts    : int  9480 968 1551 1267 1625 1946 2123 7328 810 1374 ...
 $ travel       : num  30.7 34.3 33.8 29.1 28.1 24.9 34 31.8 32.7 36.4 ...
 $ FWIHweeklyAvg: num  1.63 4.48 3.1 1.36 1.55 ...
 $ CST.NAME     : Factor w/ 7 levels "Central Scotland",..: 4 2 3 1 5 7 6 4 2 3 ...
 $ month        : chr  "March" "March" "March" "March" ...

> head(merged)
        Date patch     prod workmix_pct jobcounts travel FWIHweeklyAvg              CST.NAME month
1 2013-03-29  BVG1 2.932208         100      9480   30.7      1.627024              Scotland March
2 2013-03-29 BVG11 2.769156          10       968   34.3      4.475714   Highlands & Islands March
3 2013-03-29 BVG12 2.857344          16      1551   33.8      3.098571   North East Scotland March
4 2013-03-29 BVG13 2.870111          13      1267   29.1      1.361429      Central Scotland March
5 2013-03-29 BVG14 3.011260          17      1625   28.1      1.550000   South East Scotland March
6 2013-03-29 BVG15 3.236246          21      1946   24.9      1.392857 West Central Scotland March
```

I am trying to subset on patch BVG1 by:

```
data=merged[patch %in% c("BVG1"),]
```

But getting an error:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'patch' not found
```

Don't understand why...

I am trying to plot separate timeseries per patch using `ggplot`

This is what I have tried:

```
ggplot(data=merged, aes(x=merged$Date, y=merged$prod, group=patch)) + geom_line() + xlab("") + ylab("Weekly Prods")+ scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%Y"),breaks = "1 month")
```

This plots all patches on one graph... But I want to show BVG1 timeseries only and this is what I was trying:

```
ggplot(data=merged[patch %in% c("BVG1"),], aes(x=merged$Date, y=merged$prod, group=patch)) + geom_line() + xlab("") + ylab("Weekly Prods")+ scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%Y"),breaks = "1 month")
```

But getting the same error.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Problem solved using `[merged$patch %in% c("BVG1"),]`

Comment: Please post your update as a separate question as it is unrelated to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 data=merged[merged$patch %in% c("BVG1"),]
```

That should solve your problems. `patch` is defined in your dataframe, so you need to tell `R` where to find it.

Additionally, you may want to look at `facet_wrap` instead of subsetting. For instance, adding `+ facet_wrap(~ patch)` to your plot command should show you all patches at once. I am not sure this is what you desire as output, but I thought I should point it out as an idea...

Comment: In this case can't you just do `== "BVG1"` rather than `%in% c("BVG1")`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be data = merged[merged$patch %in% c("BVG1"),]?

Comment: Alex, using `== "BVG1"` or `%in% c("BVG1")` should both work. There are many ways to subset a dataframe. I tried to stick to the code of the Shery's code.

Comment: I think `%in%` was more efficient. This is now solved the problem. But I have an ugly looking graph as shown above... I want to plot a nice looking smooth line which I did through a timeseries object. However, it would be nice to have it in `ggplot` format.

Comment: This should be posted as a new question. But you could try `ggplot(data=merged[merged$patch %in% c("BVG1"),], aes(x=Date, y=prod), group=patch) + geom_line() + xlab("") + ylab("Weekly Prods")+ scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%Y"),breaks = "1 month")`

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
data <- subset(merged, patch == "BVG1")
```

Since you're only conditioning on `patch` being a single value, you don't need `%in%`, you can just test for equality.

When you use `subset()`, R automatically interprets variables referenced in the context of the data frame, so `merged$patch` is unnecessary.